# Create Custom UIButton - Image Quality Issue

Tags: ios, image, uibutton, transparent

I have a strange problem with my buttons in a tableView.

I want to create them via code - as there may be one or 7.

When I create

```
UIButton *testButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
testButton.frame = CGRectMake(xPos, 110, 28, 28);
testButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
```

It works, add the button perfectly. But when I scroll up and down a few times the image looses quality. (My image is a circle, transparent border - no resizing necessary it fits the frame).

If i add the same button using interface builder, scroll up and down, it remains perfect, the the other buttons have lost quality, only around the outside, when the pixels border the transparent area.

Am i missing something when i create the button using code?

Comment: I hope, you are not creating buttons on some scrolling events of the `UIScrollView`, like in `scrollViewDidScroll`. If you are, then you are placing one button on another and that's why it is seeming like loosing quality. If not, then provide more code, like, button creation and the code you are adding button to the scrollview.

Comment: I've given up trying to do it, I've to use interface builder, and use tags. But trying to subclass a UIButton in IB is causing issues. Its not seting my button the custom class, even after setting it in IB.